# How to modify Elasticsearch heap size? - jvm.options not being used

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, jvm, heap-memory

**How to permanently change the JVM heap size for Elasticsearch ?**

I edited the `jvm.options` file in `/etc/elasticsearch/` to raise the heap size to 2gb (by adding these 2 lines: `-Xms2g -Xmx2g`), but ES still starts with default heap size (990.7mb in my case).

It seems that ES doesn't read this `jvm.options` file and always uses default ones, since the JVM arguments (logged at ES launch) start with these `[-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMar...` regardless of what is set in `jvm.options`...

I also tried to set the heap size in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` (by setting `ES_JAVA_OPTS` to `"-Xms2g -Xmx2g"`), but no way.

The only way I found to temporarily modify the heap size was setting _JAVA_OPTIONS before launching Elasticsearch :

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
```

But it is clearly not a good option... Does anybody have a clue? Thanks!

Comment: How do you launch ES?

Comment: With the command `bin/elasticsearch`, from my custom install folder. Could it be of some importance ?

Comment: Yes, the files you modified are used when starting ES as a service. if you start from the bin folder, you need to modify the jvm.options that is in your config folder next to bin, but if you installed ES through a package (RPM, DEB) you don't have that folder and need to start ES as a service

Comment: You're completely right, I had two jvm.options files both in bin/ and etc/. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had 2 jvm.options files : one in `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` and one in `mycustominstallfolder/config` ... And of course I was setting the wrong one.

Thanks a lot @Val !